# Dying and repeating a while loop twice. (ROBLOX)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm trying to make a script where every second your leaderstats gains a point but when a player dies/resets their character, they get double the while loop so double the points.
I have a feeling it's because the character is being connected twice hence counting the while loop twice?

```
local Players  = game.Players

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder", Player)
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local WalkS = Instance.new("IntValue", leaderstats)
    WalkS.Name = "Walkspeed"
    WalkS.Value = 0

    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Char)
        local Humanoid = Char:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")    

        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = WalkS.Value
        
        while Humanoid do
            Humanoid.WalkSpeed = WalkS.Value
            wait(1)
            WalkS.Value = WalkS.Value + 1
        end
    end)

end)
```

I don't know how to fix this and have been trying, I just don't know anything else to use other than CharacterAdded

Answer (score 0):

When any instance gets destroyed its references (in code) don't necessarily become nil. It's important to understand that all destroy does is remove the object from workspace, remove any connections associated object has, and then lock the object from being re-added to workspace.

Eg:

```lua
local baseplate = workspace.Baseplate;
baseplate:Destroy(); -- removes it from workspace, and removes all connections
print(baseplate.Name); -- still prints "baseplate"
baseplate.Name = "test" -- works
baseplate.Parent = workspace -- errors, since it's locked
```

---

So to fix your issue, you should also make sure that the Humanoid exists in workspace

```lua
    Player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(Char)
        local Humanoid = Char:WaitForChild("Humanoid") -- also would recommend WaitForChild
        -- as humanoid may not be loaded on character added 

        Humanoid.WalkSpeed = WalkS.Value
        
        while Humanoid:IsDescendantOf(workspace) do -- check to make sure it's in the workspace
            Humanoid.WalkSpeed = WalkS.Value
            wait(1)
            WalkS.Value = WalkS.Value + 1
        end
    end)
```